# Is there a way to perform clustering for a set of multivariate Gaussian distributions?

Tags: statistics, cluster-analysis, data-mining, data-modeling, gaussian

I have a set of multivariate (2D) Gaussian distributions (represented by mean and variance) and would like to perform clustering on these distributions in a way that maintains the probabilistic Gaussian information (perhaps using the overlap of variances?).

[image]

I have done some research into clustering methods and found that DBSCAN clustering is more appropriate than K-means, as I don't know how many clusters I expect to find. However, DBSCAN makes use of a euclidean distance epsilon value to find clusters instead of using the variances of each distribution. I have also looked into Gaussian-Mixture Model methods, but they fit a set of points to a set of K Gaussian clusters, rather than fitting clusters to a set of Gaussian distributions.

Does anyone know of any additional clustering methods that might be appropriate to my needs?

Thanks!

Comment: There is python code here that implements a clustering Gaussians algorithm: https://github.com/mathDR/clustering-gaussians

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBSCAN can be used with arbitrary distances. It is *not* limited to Euclidean distance. You could employ a divergence measure, e.g. how much your Gaussians *overlap*.

However, I would suggest hierarchical clustering or Gaussian Mixture Modeling (EM).

DBSCAN is *designed* to allow Banana-shaped clusters, which are *not* well approximated by Gaussians. Your objective appear to be to merge similar Gaussians. That is better achieved by hierarchical clustering.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will have a deeper look into using hierarchical clustering.